# Copying a Large Number of Files in wwwroot with ASP.NET Core causes VS2017 to go very slow

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've create a new project with the VS2017 wizard (New Project, Web, MVC, Authentication on) and it builds and runs with no issues.  I copied  thousands of files into a subdirectory called "wwwroot/reactapp" and did nothing else. Now, every time I build the project, it take 20x longer then before.

What is VS2017 doing with those files? I'm not deploying them, I'm just doing a Build/All. I would think it would not touch them or care but it clearly does.

Comment: Did you check your iis ...in my case it was dumping everything in temp folder hence a lot of time

Comment: if any of these files are .cs or .cshtml, the folder gets included. You can check your .csproj file for what changes have occurred.